# Yocto Package have unmet dependencies while installing deb file

Tags: arm, yocto, apt, libssl, libgcc

I want to install **ws-rtsp-proxy_1.8-4_armhf.deb** in my **armhf7 board**
while doing this I got the error. But I have all the dependencies which I have attached below.

```
root@rt-work:~# apt-get install ./ws-rtsp-proxy_1.8-4_armhf.deb 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ws-rtsp-proxy : Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:3.5) but linaro-7.2-r2017.11 is installed
                 Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not installable
                 Depends: systemd but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

But `libgcc` and `libssl1` are already there as you can see:

```
root@rt-work:~# dpkg --list | grep -i "libgcc1"
ii  libgcc1                                                       linaro-7.2-r2017.11                                  armhf        GNU cc ands
root@rt-work:~# dpkg --list | grep -i "libssl*"
ii  libss2                                                        1.43.5-r0                                            armhf        Ext2 Filess
ii  libssl1.0.2                                                   1.0.2n-r0                                            armhf        Secure Socr
ii  libssp-dev                                                    linaro-7.2-r2017.11                                  armhf        GNU stack s
ii  libssp0                                                       linaro-7.2-r2017.11                                  armhf
```

uname -a

```
Linux rt-work 4.4.138-cip25-yocto-standard #3 SMP PREEMPT Fri Feb 7 12:29:37 IST 2020 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
Version: 2.1.0
Poky (Yocto Project Reference Distro) 2.4.2
```

How could I solve the issue?

**Edit** 
I download the ws-rtsp-proxy_1.8-4_armhf.deb from this site-->https://streamedian.com/ and i try to install it in my  armhf board. The deb i have downloaded is Raspbian 9.3(.deb)

or libgcc and libssl are already present in my rootfs

Comment: I think you need to add a bit more detail to the question about you setup.

Is ws-rtsp-proxy_1.8-4_armhf.deb a package you built using Yocto, and is the rootfs you're trying to install it to also from that build?

Comment: we cant mix debian distro generated debs

Comment: @Khem Please check edit i took raspbian 9.3(.deb)

Comment: @rahul Khem's comment is still valid, you can't use packages from Debian/Raspbian/Other Non-Yocto sources in the system built with Yocto. You need deb's for the distribution you are using.

Comment: @rahul, you have to build your own packages  you should look into https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/TipsAndTricks/EnablingAPackageFeed